# problems with get_absolute_url()

Tags: django

Please, I need your help.
I can't return urls from model to template. I think that problem in method `get_absolute_url`. This is the error that I get:

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'product_list' with arguments '('saws',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['$']
```

Code is:

```
# models
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Category', max_length=100, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, db_index=True,
                            unique=True)
...
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('core:product_list',
                       args=[self.slug])
```

urls.py

```
app_name = 'core'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.ProductView.as_view(), name='product_list'),]
    #url(r'^$', views.ProductView.as_view(), name='product_list'),
```

views.py

```
class ProductView(generic.ListView):
    queryset = Product.objects.filter(available=True)
    paginate_by = 3
    form_class = QuantityForm
    categories = Category.objects.all()


    def category_slugg(self, category_slug=None):
        if category_slug:
            category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
            return category


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProductView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['Products'] = self.form_class
        context['categories'] = self.categories
        context['category'] = self.category_slugg
        return context
```

html

```
<li {% if not category %}class="selected"{% endif %}>
 <a href="{{ categories.get_absolute_url }}"All</a>
</li>
{% for c in categories %}
 <a href="{{ c.get_absolute_url }}">{{ c.name }}</a> <!--if delete 'c.get_absolute_url', except escape-->
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: A `$` is *not* a valid slug. So it looks like you are slugifying the wrong way.

Comment: Please provide the code for your `ProductView` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your url `path` doesn't accept any args but then you pass it a slug.

You need to allow the slug in the URL;

```
path('<slug:category_slug>/', views.ProductView.as_view(), name='product_list'),
```

There's an example of this in the django docs here; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#examples

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `args=[self.slug]` to `kwargs={'slug': self.slug}`, then in urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<str:slug>/', views.ProductView.as_view(), name='product_list'),
    ]
```

The idea is that get_absolute_url receives kwargs from urls.

Comment: The path converters offer a specific `slug` type so that would be better than using `str`; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#path-converters